# What's the point of primary dense indexing?

Tags: performance, database-design, index

I'm refreshing my basic knowledge of indexing specifically to database indexing. Pratically, I don't put much attention to how it works internally I just do that `CREATE INDEX index_name` and assume that it will create such block based on the column supplied for later faster retrival. So I came to this *primary dense index* topic somewhere on the internet that  mentions : *In a dense index, a record is created for every search key valued in the database*. I assumed that, for every index record in the index table is mapped with exactly a row in the database table. In this case the number of rows in the index table is same with the number of rows in the database. How does this even improve the searching?

Comment: Thanks. I actually quite struggled to get this one in my mind. I think after that B-tree data structure mentioned things start to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, it groups together the same values allowing fast sequential reads rather than slow random reads.

Second, only the key and a pointer are stored in the index so one unit of IO will return information about a great many more rows than would a read of the data.

Third, it is combined with sparse indexes to form B-Tree indexes. These are ubiquitous, having great properties covering many common scenarios.